# ASP.Net Core, Entity Framework and MySQL Gives a Create exception? Any ideas why?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a working ASP.Net Core application with SQL Server and Entity Framework. I use DI to inject the database context. The solution has a web project and a data project. I am looking to move to MySql and have made some small changes to the code.

Running the application gives me the error

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
  Source=MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
```

These are my changes (apart from connection string which I changed and know it works):

In Startup.cs in the web project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddDbContext<DatabaseModel>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Dev")));
   ...
}
```

Installed using Nuget into the data project

```
MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore v8.0.22
(this installs Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational and MySql.Data)
```

I cannot reference `using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;` as I get an error (red line under **Extensions**) so something hasn't been referenced but it compiles ok.

In DatabaseModel.cs in the data project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;         
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;        <========= this has been added by me
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public partial class DatabaseModel : DbContext  <========= no changes to this class
{
   ....
}
```

Any ideas? I have used MySQL in ASP.Net but not Core so I am thinking that I have a missing package but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the solution is downgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to version 3.1.10.

I had it at V5.0.0

Comment: If you do want to use Microsoft.EntityFramework 5.0, you can try switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.0-alpha.2) (or later).

Answer (score 0):

Please try using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore instead of MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this solve the problem?